# having problems in module

Tags: python, discord.py

i am making a discord bot heres the code and the error

```
f = open("rules.txt","r")
rules = f.readlines()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows10\OneDrive\Desktop\YourBot\bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    rules = f.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\Windows10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
```

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Try
First:

```
f = open('rules.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
rules = f.readlines()
```

Second:

```
f = open('rules.txt', 'r', errors = 'ignore')
rules = f.readlines()
```